# SyntaxError: invalid syntax, when import spacy

Tags: python

Good morning everyone! I'm having trouble with this error that I get when I try to `import spacy` (NLP library) in python, if anyone knows why I'm having this error, please let me know.

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ioann\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import spacy
  File "C:\Users\ioann\spacy.py", line 1
    import
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Don't name your script the same as the package or module: you'll be importing your script instead of the package or module.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't written your import command properly

Try this:

```
import spacy
```